# Local Sqlite3 database with PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor

Tags: python, php, sql, sqlite

I want to learn using Databases with **PHP**, and I want to use local database with **PHP**, I don't want to connect to any remote database (mysql, etc.). I just want to practice with SQLi attacks and more. My website will run locally on my Local Area Network.

can I just run queries to my sqlite3 database file with **PHP**?

**Python Example:**

```
import sqlite3

# connect to local database
connection = sqlite3.connect('/database/mydb.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

# simple query example
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS...')
```

How can I do that with **PHP**?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php

class MyDB extends SQLite3
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->open('mydb.db');
    }
}

$db = new MyDB();

$db->query(
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS groups (
        group_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        name TEXT NOT NULL
    );"
);

?>
```

- Note: The created table ("groups") is just for testing purpose

Comment: What is `SQLite3`? Throws me an error `SQLite3 not found ...`.

Comment: The SQLite3 extension is enabled by default as of PHP 5.3.0. It's possible to disable it by using --without-sqlite3 at compile time [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.installation.php). I've php7.3 and works without error in linux. If you're on windows, check the link above or check the page for possible installation issues.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't able to respond earlier. I'm confused, PHP shows in the browser but you (or your local host) use an OS. Could you run this PHP?: <?php
echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion();
echo '<br>OS: ' . PHP_OS;
?>